Renaming jpg files in sequential order in Mac or Windos
I have 100 files that are named 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg....100.jpg in a folder. I would like to rename them sequentially starting from number 83. Eg: 1.jpg becomes 83.jpg, 2.jpg becomes 84.jpg and so on..
I am looking for a OSX command or batch script in Windows.
Thanks.
I have tried this where i=83, but it always starts renaming 1,jpg as 100.jpg, 2.jpg as 101.jpg..so on.
i=1
for f in *; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && mv "$f" $((i++)).txt
done

Came across this script in stack forum but not sure how to set the start number to be 83 instead of default 1
ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.txt"; done 


Your first script will definitely not rename 1.jpg to 100.jpg. Please [edit] your question to describe the problem you're having and show a [mcve] version of your code that's exhibiting the problem. Your second script is using an antipattern, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, and has other issues that http://shellcheck.net could correct for you.

Also, * will expand to 100.jpg 101.jpg 1.jpg 2.jpg in that order. Glob expansions are sorted alphabetically (according to the current locale), not numerically. Try it out for yourself: echo * – specified by POSIX: "If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale."

Aside from the artificial limitations to use a "shell script" instead of an actual programming language, if you know that your files are numbered in a certain range. I would simply start with a loop of some sorts that goes from top to bottom numbers (i.e. 100 to 1), and simply renames "$i.jpg" to "$(i+82).jpg" in whatever way the shell does arithmetic. Note the "backwards" loop, or else it will rename "1.jpg" to "83.jpg" and destroy the original "83.jpg", and actually renaming it again to 165.jpg further down the loop. Starting from the top avoids this.

Also, the current script will rename the first file (100.jpg, as knittl points out) to 85.jpg overwriting the original 85.jpg without any indication that it's done so. Then later, when it gets to 87.jpg, it'll rename it again, to... well, whatever number it's up to by then. Always always always use mv -i or mv -n when doing automated/bulk renames, to avoid accidental overwrites like this.

If you have 100 files that are named 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg....100.jpg and you rename 1.jpg to 83.jpg then you just wiped out the original 83.jpg so you can't just rename to other numbers with the same suffix starting from 1.jpg.
Try this, untested:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS='.' read -r num sfx; do
    mv -- "${num}.${sfx}" "$(( num + 82 )).${sfx}"
done < <(printf '%s\n' *.jpg | sort -rn)

Using sort -rn is crucial so that 83.jpg and higher get renamed before 1.jpg can overwrite 83.jpg.

It's probably a lot easier to perform calculations on the numeric part of the filename than assuming a certain order when iterating the files.
* will expand to 100.jpg 101.jpg 1.jpg 2.jpg in that order. Glob expansions are sorted alphabetically (according to the current locale), not numerically. Try it out for yourself: echo * – specified by POSIX:

If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale.

But your task is simple, you want to add 82 to the number in each file name:
for f in *; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
      num="${f%.jpg}"
      mv "$f" "$((num+82))".jpg
    fi
done

Do note that this will overwrite any existing file of the same name. So the original 83.jpg would be overwritten by your 1.jpg (+82)! I see two solutions to this problem:

Rename in reverse (as suggested in the comments under your questions), e.g. by having a loop counter and building the file names in the loop instead of iterating the files directly. Something like i=100; while [ "$i" -gt 0 ]; do mv "$i.jpg" "$((i+82)).jpg"; i="$((i-1))"; done. This could also handle uncommon file names that contain special characters or line breaks.
Rename to a different name first, such as 83.jpg.renamed and then remove the suffix in a follow-up step.

